# How to make MyHDL generate variable with arbitrary width in process?

Tags: python, fpga, myhdl

I would like to do a sum of signals that I have in a list, naturally I have used variable and for (as I would in VHDL):

```
    @always_comb
    def sum():
        sum = 0
        for i in range(len(summands)):
            sum = sum + summands[i]
        product.next = sum
```

The problem is that this will use integer (in VHDL) for sum variable, which is not much useful when the width of sum will be more than 32bits.

So I tried to do something like this:

```
    @always_comb
    def sum():
        sum = intbv(0, min=vmin, max=vmax)
        for i in range(len(summands)):
            sum = sum + summands[i]
        product.next = sum
```

I get following error (during conversion):

```
    Type mismatch with earlier assignment: sum
```

Which I don't understand how to work around. I guess it gets the value of intbv in sum as integer and therefore is different type.

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make very ugly workaround:

```
@always_comb
def sum():
    sum = intbv(0, min=vmin, max=vmax)
    for i in range(len(summands)):
        sum = intbv(sum + summands[i], min=vmin, max=vmax)
    product.next = sum
```

In this manner it will generate correct VHDL:

```
IIR_SOS_INST_0_PRODUCTS_1_SUM: process (sos_inst_0_products_1_summands) is
    variable sum: signed(44 downto 0);
begin
    sum := to_signed(0, 45);
    for i in 0 to 21-1 loop
        sum := to_signed((sum + sos_inst_0_products_1_summands(i)), 45);
    end loop;
    sos_inst_0_b1p <= sum;
end process IIR_SOS_INST_0_PRODUCTS_1_SUM;
```

But the performance of the simulation suffers considerably on creating a new intbv object on every assignment to sum.

Comment: I don't think it's _that_ ugly... anyway, what type is `sos_inst_0_products_1_summands` now? still integer?

Comment: Hi, that will end up being signed.Uglyness is in the fact the during simulation it is creating always new intbv object which takes time..

Answer (score 0):

For people who come across this in future. You can create the variable outside the `@always_comb` (or `@always`) function:

```
sum = intbv(0, min=vmin, max=vmax)
```

The syntax to assign to that variable is:

```
sum[:] = 0
```

The given example would then become:

```
sum = intbv(0, min=vmin, max=vmax)

@always_comb
def sum():
    sum[:] = 0
    for i in range(len(summands)):
        sum[:] = sum + summands[i]
    product.next = sum
```

This [page](http://docs.myhdl.org/en/stable/manual/conversion.html) in the MyHDL manual provides more detail.